# angular5 - block assets if opened in new tab directly, outside the application

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-routing

**Angular-5:** I have configured **.angular-cli.Json** file as per below link, I want to use assets like images, JSON, js in my project, ***when I open the assets path in new tab I don't want to display the content***, can anyone please let me know how can I handle this?

**For example** if i open 'http://localhost:4200/assets/json/environment/localhost.json' in new tab it should not display the content. but i have to use this json file in my application.

Angular-cli.json configuration - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli

Comment: upon research i think we can fix this issue by doing modifications in nginx.config file. But not sure how to do that